# IIS full pathname incorrect

Tags: iis, iis-7, path, http-status-code-404

I have created a WebSite in IIS, with the following correct full pathname:

```
d:\inetpub\wwwroot\nameofsite
```

When I try and browse for this site, I get a 404 resource missing error.  From the webserver, the error states it is looking for the resource in `d:\inetpub\webmail\nameofsite`.  When I move the resource to this location, it works.  I don't understand why it would claim the resources are in `inetpub\webmail` dir, when I never specified it there.  I deleted the site, and created it again, in case I did it by accident, but it still does it.

What is going wrong?

[image: 404 error]

[image: IIS Advanced settings]

[image: IIS Basic Settings]

[image: Forwarding]

[image: IIS Binding]